# php How to check if an array of numbers are all positive

Tags: php

I put 3 user inputs into an array. all numbers. and I want to check if all 3 numbers are positive.

The code below will return true when 1 of them is positive.

```
        foreach($array as $value){
            if($value >= 0){
                return TRUE;
            }else{
                return FALSE;
            }
        }
```

Using heybignick 's suggestion. the below code seems to give me the desired result.

```
$array = array(1,2,3,4,-5);


if(min($array)<0){
  echo "negative";  
}else{
    echo "positive";    
}
```

Comment: Then just change the condition and return false as soon as you encounter a negative one and if all go through you can return true at the end.

Comment: that is smart, will try this

Comment: FYI, @codenoob, I think you mean "non-negative" when you say positive. If you truly mean "positive," then the code in the various solutions is wrong.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Could you just use min to get the desired result?

```
return min($array) >= 0
```

Comment: This is concise but wasteful. (If the first number is negative, why are we bothering to look at all of them and find the smallest number?)

Answer (score 4):

Implementing @Rizier123's suggested fix:

```
foreach($array as $value) {
    if($value < 0) {
        return FALSE;
    }
}
return TRUE;
```