# PHP Check if multiple values in array are all positive or all negative or partly

Tags: php

I have an array with 2 possible values `negative` and `positive`. If all the values are `positive` my function has to return `positive`.

If all values are `negative` my function has to return `negative`. If the values are a mix then my function has to return `partly`.

My code always returns `partly`, unfortunately, I don't know why.

```
 const RESULT_OF_SEARCH_POSITIVE = "positive";
    const RESULT_OF_SEARCH_NEGATIVE = "negative";
    const RESULT_OF_SEARCH_PARTLY = "partly";

    ...

private function calculateResultOfSearch(array $imagesResultArray)
  {
   if (array_unique($imagesResultArray) === self::RESULT_OF_SEARCH_POSITIVE) {
       return self::RESULT_OF_SEARCH_POSITIVE;
   } elseif(array_unique($imagesResultArray) === self::RESULT_OF_SEARCH_NEGATIVE) 
     {
       return self::RESULT_OF_SEARCH_NEGATIVE;
   } else {
       return self::RESULT_OF_SEARCH_PARTLY;
    }
}
```

Comment: How is count, which returns an integer supposed to be equal to a String with the value of positive or negative?

Comment: @maio290 my bad I am retarded I think I updated OP

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php How to check if an array of numbers are all positive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38087331/php-how-to-check-if-an-array-of-numbers-are-all-positive)

Comment: @Jean-MarcZimmer no it's not a duplicate, my question has nothing to do with numbers and there are 3 conditions not 1

Comment: Oh, OK, sorry. I though you were talking of positive and negative values ! My bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A much simplified version of the code which if `array_unique` just has 1 value, then return it (also I only call it once rather than repeatedly calling it which is very inefficient)...

```
private function calculateResultOfSearch(array $imagesResultArray)
{
    $unique = array_unique($imagesResultArray);
    return (count($unique) == 1 ) ? $unique[0]
          : self::RESULT_OF_SEARCH_PARTLY;
}
```

**Edit:**
I am unfortuantly back after realising I've wasted 20% of the lines I wrote :(  If all the items are the same, I can just return the first item of the array passed in so I don't need to store the result of `array_unique()` at all :-/

```
private function calculateResultOfSearch(array $imagesResultArray)
{
    return ( count(array_unique($imagesResultArray)) == 1 ) ? 
            $imagesResultArray[0]: RESULT_OF_SEARCH_PARTLY;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

As we know the `count()` function always returns the count of the array. So it goes to the else case in every match of the condition.

You should try something like this:

```
class Demo{
    const RESULT_OF_SEARCH_POSITIVE = "positive";
    const RESULT_OF_SEARCH_NEGATIVE = "negative";
    const RESULT_OF_SEARCH_PARTLY = "partly";

function calculateResultOfSearch(array $imagesResultArray)
{
  if (count(array_count_values($imagesResultArray)) == 1 && $imagesResultArray[0] === self::RESULT_OF_SEARCH_POSITIVE) {
   return current($imagesResultArray);
} elseif(count(array_count_values($imagesResultArray)) == 1 && $imagesResultArray[0]== self::RESULT_OF_SEARCH_NEGATIVE) {
  return self::RESULT_OF_SEARCH_NEGATIVE;
} else {
  return self::RESULT_OF_SEARCH_PARTLY;
   }
  }
}

$demo = new Demo();    
print_r($demo->calculateResultOfSearch(["positive","positive"]));
```

`array_count_values()` returns an array using the values of the array as keys and their frequency in the array as values.

Here is a simple way to check the values of an array containing the same value using `array_count_values` function and count if all keys are the same this should equal.

[Reference](https://daveismyname.blog/checking-all-array-keys-are-the-same-with-php)

Comment: I edited OP I forgot to remove the count() but it still doesnt work because array_unique returns an array not a string

Comment: @Michael, please try this code, I think this will help you as you are looking.

Answer (score 0):

You're comparing `(count(array_unique($imagesResultArray))` which return an `int` with `self::RESULT_OF_SEARCH_POSITIVE` or `self::RESULT_OF_SEARCH_NEGATIVE` which return a `string` equals to either `"positive"` or `"negative"` so it's always false.

You need to change your conditions.

**EDIT after OP's edit**

PHP: array_unique

> Takes an input array and returns a new array without duplicate values.

In your case you might want to check if the resulting array only has one element equals to `"positive"` or `"negative"`.

```
$newArray = array_unique($imagesResultArray);

if (count($newArray) == 1 && $newArray[0] === self::RESULT_OF_SEARCH_POSITIVE) {
    return self::RESULT_OF_SEARCH_POSITIVE;
} elseif(count($newArray) == 1 && $newArray[0] === self::RESULT_OF_SEARCH_NEGATIVE) {
    return self::RESULT_OF_SEARCH_NEGATIVE;
} else {
    return self::RESULT_OF_SEARCH_PARTLY;
}
```

Comment: @Michael I just saw it's the same as mine, maybe it's not worth putting a new one ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
const RESULT_OF_SEARCH_POSITIVE = "positive";
const RESULT_OF_SEARCH_NEGATIVE = "negative";
const RESULT_OF_SEARCH_PARTLY = "partly";

...

private function calculateResultOfSearch(array $imagesResultArray)
{
    if (!in_array(RESULT_OF_SEARCH_NEGATIVE)) {
        return self::RESULT_OF_SEARCH_POSITIVE;
    } elseif(!in_array(RESULT_OF_SEARCH_POSITIVE)) {
        return self::RESULT_OF_SEARCH_NEGATIVE;
    } else {
        return self::RESULT_OF_SEARCH_PARTLY;
    }
}
```

Comment: This didn't work or you just didn't try it ? (No offense, just because if it failed I want to know it)

Answer (score 0):

With your guys answers I came to this "clean" solution.

```
private function calculateResultOfSearch(array $imagesResultArray)
{
    $results = array_unique($imagesResultArray);

    if(count($results) == 1 && $results[0] === self::RESULT_OF_SEARCH_NEGATIVE) {
        return self::RESULT_OF_SEARCH_NEGATIVE;
    }

    if(count($results) == 1 && $results[0] === self::RESULT_OF_SEARCH_POSITIVE) {
        return self::RESULT_OF_SEARCH_POSITIVE;
    }

    return self::RESULT_OF_SEARCH_PARTLY;
}
```

Comment: Your answer is my latest edit to mine, maybe it's not worth putting a new one ?

Comment: @Nesku It's not the same actually

Comment: Right I didn't see you removed the `else` to make the code cleaner, but the actual solution to your problem is the same.